# Excel VLOOKUP/ INDEX multiple times based on value

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, match, vlookup

[image: Pic1ReferenceTable]

[image: Pic2InOut]

So I want to be able to change the values from Pic2 in rows "ZERO" and "LINE-IN" and have it reference the table to output the value from the even number of rows.  In Pic2 if I enter "AA","CC","BB" into row "ZERO" and "3","2","1" into row "LINE-IN" then it would take "AA" from "ZERO" on Pic2 go to column A on Pic1 and find the match, then Look within row 1 Pic1 to find "3", then output "Z" from row 2 into the "LINE-OUT" row. So, the value "CC" in row "ZERO" with value of "2" in row "LINE-IN" will output the value of "X".

I have came across a few possible ways to accomplish this using VLOOKUP, INDEX, MATCH, and IF.  All solutions and the ways I can think to do what I asking requires to build multiple tables and that doesn't seem very practical the way I am imagining.

I am really looking for one or two formulas that I can reference instead of making several different tables to accomplish the same thing.

Thanks for any help or guidance towards a solution and sorry about having to follow the links for the pics.

Comment: A quick note, the merged cells in column A might make this trickier than need be.  Can you use helper columns?

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused about how you've set your table up.  If you set it up as follows:

[image]

then it is a very simple Index/Match function.

For instance, if the tables were arranged as above, then the formula in cell B8 that will change as you change cells B6 and B7 is:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$D$4,MATCH(B7,$A$1:$A$4,0),MATCH(B6,$A$1:$D$1,0))
```

and you only need one table

Comment: well I had the table set up for manual reference also I think where the flaw in my thinking was.  I think that should solve the issue I am having.  Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: @NewToTheGame you may complete the step by 'accept'-ing the answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) . It'll remove this question from the 'unanswered' list. ( :